# Jmeter get requests failing to exit for existing response

Tags: jmeter

I want to let JMeter exit while controller when response value `"model_name": "Model-Corpus-JMeter2-0001-v1-8k"` is found in response data.

**sample response data:**

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "valid_model_list": [{
            "meta_data": {
                "corpus_list": [
                    "test1"
                ],
                "id": "1",
                "sample_rate": 16000,
                "test_duration": "0.17 hrs"
            },
            "model_name": "Model-Corpus-JMeter2-0001-v1-8k",
            "status": "ok"
        },
        {
            "meta_data": {
                "corpus_list": [
                    "test1"
                ],
                "id": "2",
                "sample_rate": 16000,
                "test_duration": "0.17 hrs"
            },
            "model_name": "testmod2-v1-8k",
            "status": "ok"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have set **while controller condition** `${__jexl3("${model_name}" != "Model-Corpus-JMeter2-0001-v1-8k",)}`

The JSON expression is tested works to extract a list of "model_name".

however, the GET request isn't exiting when the response value is already there.

**Debug Sampler:** captured    `model_name_18=Model-Corpus-JMeter2-0001-v1-8k`

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your "sample response data" is not a valid JSON, you won't be able to use JSON Extractor on invalid JSON objects. Check it yourself - https://jsonlint.com/
2. Even if your JSON is correct your JSON Extractor configuration will return **the first** model name, not the "list", to get the "list" you will need to set "Match No" to `-1`
3. It's not clear what is the value of the `model_name` variable, you can check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)
4. You're stating that your While Controller condition is `${__jexl3("${model_name}" != "${modelnameresult}",)}` and your screenshot shows different setup

I think it would be easier to go for [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) instead.

Comment: Why regular expression should be used in this case?

Comment: I have tried both , same failed result. ${__jexl3("${model_name}" != "${modelnameresult}",)} and ${__jexl3("${model_name}" != "$modelnameresult",)}

Comment: model_name_18=Model-Corpus-JMeter2-0001-v1-8k is captured in debug sampler. what should be the while condition to handle it?

Comment: Theoretically `${__jexl3("${model_name_18}" != "${modelnameresult}",)}`, however I repeat, there might be a better way to wait until the desired value is in the response

Comment: right, seems I get the result I wanted when set the json extractor match no. to -1, all model_name returned but the specific one has model_name_xx numbering append behind, can I just find a way by modifying the while condition to match it? ${__jexl3("${model_name}"  <= maybe this part

Comment: In that case `${__jexl3("${__V(model_name_${__intSum(${model_name_matchNr},-1,)})}" != "${modelnameresult}",)}`, more information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: there is an error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${model_name_matchNr}"

Comment: i tweaked jsonpath expression to `$..valid_model_list[?(@.model_name =~ /.*Model-Corpus-JMeter2-0001-v1-8k/i)]` and while condition to `${__jexl3("${model_name_matchNr}" != "1",)}` the result is good. I need to change the jsonpath expression to use variable, as in previous POST request, variable was used.  what is the correct syntax to replace `Model-Corpus-JMeter2-0001-v1-8k `  to `Model-Test-${variable}-${counter}-v1-8k` ?